# Which HSTS preload list is used by which browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, https, hsts

I've been reading various informations about Google and Firefox using an HSTS preload list.

- it seems that there is a generic list here : https://hstspreload.org/
- and that Chrome uses the one from Chromium here :
  https://www.chromium.org/hsts/
- and Firefox uses the one here :
  https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc

Does Safari or Opera use a HSTS preload list ? Which one ? What is the relationship between the 3 list cited above ?

Thank you

Comment: For example, the only TLD listed in Firefox is "google", but I can confirm that Safari is also using HSTS for dev, foo, page, app, chrome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The defacto central master list for [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) is managed by Chromium / Google
at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json .

A list of Browsers supporting HSTS (and presumably having preload lists) can be found at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security#Browser_support).
Being closed source, information on how Opera, Safari, IE, etc. handle their preloaded lists seem to be unavailable.

The Microsoft Edge Team state [in their Blog](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/06/09/http-strict-transport-security-comes-to-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-8-1-and-windows-7/), that

> Like other browsers which have implemented this feature, Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11 base their preload list on the Chromium [HSTS preload list](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/).

For Firefox, the list at [/source/mozilla/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc) is generated by the file
[/source/mozilla/security/manager/tools/getHSTSPreloadList.js](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/source/mozilla/security/manager/tools/getHSTSPreloadList.js), where we can see from the line

```
const SOURCE = "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json?format=TEXT";
```

that it is merely a clone of the "master list", parsed into Firefox` format.
All it does is an additional verification run for each domain in the list to be available and have the required HSTS header (by connecting to it; which it seems to do daily, from the vcs log).

Palemoon [follows this procedure](https://github.com/MoonchildProductions/Pale-Moon/issues/62) and it is likely that other browser vendors do the same.
So it seems the relationship between your lists is: there is only one.

Comment: Please change the URL for Google Chrome to the following:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json

Currently they are pointing to `main` branch instead of `master`

Updating as I was looking for a solution to an issue and found your answer pointing to old file

Answer (score 0):

From your [first link](https://hstspreload.org):

> Most major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE 11 and Edge)
>   also have HSTS preload lists based on the Chrome list. (See the HSTS
>   compatibility matrix.)

Comment: Yes the question is more about what "based" means in the sentence above. Is it copied ? Inspired from ? Reviewed ?

Comment: As I understand it, it’s integrated into the individual browsers lists every so often.

Comment: And individual browsers may add to that list too.